# Font Awesome Icons as squares

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, html

I have been trying to migrate my html css and javascript static website to a wordpress dynamic theme. Everything worked fine and looks perfect but for some reason my font awesome icons appear as squares.

This is the website https://www.anasdahshan.me

if anyone can help me it would be great thank you so much.

```
<!-- Font Awesome Icon -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/all.min.css" />
```

```
            <ul class="social-icons ml-md-n2 justify-content-center justify-content-md-start">
              <li class="social-icons-linkedin"><a data-toggle="tooltip" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/" target="_blank" title="LinkedIn" data-original-title="LinkedIn"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
              <li class="social-icons-github"><a data-toggle="tooltip" href="https://github.com/" target="_blank" title="Github" data-original-title="GitHub"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
              <li class="social-icons-twitter"><a data-toggle="tooltip" href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" title="Twitter" data-original-title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li class="social-icons-instagram"><a data-toggle="tooltip" href="https://instagram.com/" target="_blank" title="Instagram" data-original-title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Solution:
Just use the html code given with the font awesome kit without adding any php tags.

The html should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxx.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxx.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since it no longer made sense with your edit, here's my comment:

Comment: Did you receive that css file to copy and paste to your site from Font Awesome? When I've gone and created a Font Awesome kit, they always provide a line of JS to paste into your site. I'd recommend doing that instead as there are relative links in your CSS code to files that aren't on your site. E.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/abc123.css" crossorigin="anonymous">` Note that for version 5 of FA the only accepted way on their site is using JS.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly when I used the html code from font awesome

Comment: Awesome! I'll post it as an answer then so you can upvote and/or mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should be using Font Awesome's provided `<link>` or `<script>` tag(s) that they give you with your kit. It should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxx.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or if you prefer the JS method:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxx.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Copying and pasting the code from their CSS file to your local one isn't advisable because there are relative links to Font Awesome custom fonts that can't/won't be included in your site's files. (As @Alexander Holsgrove points out)

Answer (score 1):

Your [all.min.css](https://anasdahshan.me/wp-content/themes/wp-AnasDahshan/css/all.min.css) font is loaded onto your site, but can you please check you have a `webfonts` directory with files such as `fa-solid-900.woff` and `fa-solid-900.svg` - At the bottom of the all.min.css file you will see the @font-face declarations and the required paths relative to your CSS file eg `src:url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot);`

The CSS class names and `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"` look fine otherwise, so I suspect it's just a case of missing the font files (or the path being incorrect)